# Streamreader with multiple files

Tags: c#, streamreader

I can't seem to find any questions/solutions throughout the web that correlate to this particular scenario, so I figured I'd give a breakdown on what I'm trying to achieve using the StreamReader type.

Basically I have 2 files with unbalanced line counts i.e. data1.txt contains contains 20 lines, whereas data2.txt contains 10, so I'm using StreamReader to first read data from both .txt files, and I was thinking I could use the while (((ts.transaction = t.ReadLine()) !=null)||((ms.master = t.ReadLine()) !=null)) to read the total lines from both files, and then I could continue with applying additional logic, to merge my data into a 3rd file.

However when I run the following below, I'm running into a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" likely because of the unbalanced line count? It seems to work when I replace "||" in the while statement with "&&" however I'm unable to print the total number of lines from both files.

At the moment I'm just appending the text to richTextBox1 in order to test my data output for now. I was seeing if there's a better way I can go about using the OR clause, or whether I'm even going about this while condition the right way?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Read Transaction File
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Clear();
        StreamReader t = new StreamReader(@"c:\data1.txt");
        StreamReader m = new StreamReader(@"c:\data2.txt");

        transaction_storage ts = new transaction_storage();
        master_storage ms = new master_storage();

        while (((ts.transaction = t.ReadLine()) !=null)||((ms.master = t.ReadLine()) !=null))
        //while ((ts.transaction = t.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            ms.m_index = Convert.ToInt32(ms.master.Substring(0, 2));

            ts.t_index = Convert.ToInt32(ts.transaction.Substring(0, 2));
            ts.t_name = ts.transaction.Substring(2, 10);
            ts.t_item = ts.transaction.Substring(10, 17);
            ts.t_amount = Convert.ToDouble(ts.transaction.Substring(ts.transaction.Length -7, 7));
            string transaction_data = (ts.t_index.ToString() + " " + ts.t_name + " " + ts.t_item + " " + ts.t_amount + "\n");
            string master_data = (ms.m_index.ToString());

            richTextBox1.AppendText(transaction_data);
            richTextBox1.AppendText(master_data);
        }

        t.Close();
        m.Close();

    }


    class master_storage
    {
        public int m_index;
        public string master;
    }

    class transaction_storage
    {

        public int t_index;
        public string t_name;
        public string t_item;
        public double t_amount;
        public string transaction;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Why are you trying to process both streams at the same time? Process one file, then the other. Don't cross the streams!

Comment: In which line does the exception occur?

Comment: why didnt you read one file from begin to end then the other?

Comment: Yeah, I was just curious if crossing multiple streams into a single While statement was a possibility, however it's sounding like this is not the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just read both files first and then use a simple for loop to do the logic afterwards:

```
var linesOfFile1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\data1.txt");
var linesOfFile2 = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\data2.txt");

for(int i = 0; i < Math.Min(linesOfFile1.Length, linesOfFile2.Length); i++) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks darthmaim, I experimented with the for loop as well, and it looks like if I want to process both streams, then this seems to be the most ideal solution aside from streaming them individually.